# Extreme zoom-in in d3 graph causes area (or line) graph to disappear

Tags: d3.js

I try to use the zoom functionality of d3, but my graphs keep disappearing if I zoom in too far.

See https://bl.ocks.org/everhardt/3d6b9e127669c59251234f4c7f157fe2 for an example. If you zoom in to a visible domain of ~13 minutes or less, you'll see that the area graph will disappear. Zooming-out enough will make it appear again.

I got similar results using a line graph instead of an area graph.

What causes this? The axis is rendering properly. If I look at the raw SVG, I don't see any strange behaviour. Is it a rounding error somewhere?

By the way, my gist is a fork of Mike Bostock's https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/431a331294d2b5ddd33f947cf4c81319. I've only set the maximum scale factor to Infinity (in `scaleExtent`)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the data is not available to support the higher zoom levels. Or it may try and estimate it, but can only go so far. e.g. If you zoom in so that your x-axis is only showing hours - for which there are no values - then no graph information can be shown.

You could prove this by adding hour, minute and second columns to your data then seeing how far you can zoom in.

For a better user experience it may be a good idea to keep the scaleExtent to something that doesn't mess it up.

Comment: I'm not sure about that: the month+year from the CSV are parsed as a Date (using `d3.timeParse`) and thus are precise up to a millisecond.

Comment: I agree by the way with your remark on capping the scaleExtent. The issue is that I'd like to create a graph that can zoom in up a domain of ~ 5 seconds and that doesn't work. What I did work out now, is that if I alter the CSV to contain only the Jan 2010 and Feb 2010 datapoints, I can zoom in a lot further. Could there maybe be a limit on the dimensions of a plot? When zooming in very far, the (invisible part of) the plot gets very wide..

Comment: I've created this http://plnkr.co/edit/fNvTNsys1gTOzq9mfpY1?p=preview which has the zoom and translation on the display. I have had a fiddle round with it, but can't see any real correlations - it does seem to disappear at different points depending of where you initiate the zoom.

Comment: Thanks, and indeed: me neither. I've just posted this question on GitHub as well, see https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/111

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser limitation, see https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/111.